# d3 selectAll vs jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, d3.js

from the documentation:

> d3.selectAll(selector)
>
> Selects all elements that match the specified selector. The elements
>   will be selected in document traversal order (top-to-bottom). If no
>   elements in the current document match the specified selector, returns
>   the empty selection.

Now in practice:

```
<div class="nv-series"></div>
<div class="nv-series"></div>
<div class="nv-series"></div>
```

script:

```
console.log(d3.selectAll(".nv-series").length);
console.log($(".nv-series").length);
```

d3 logs 1! and jquery 3!

This is probably normal, but I don't get it. Can someone explain why d3 logs 1?

Comment: They should be the same, try using 'div' instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `.length` —— use `.size()`, as in:

```
console.log(d3.selectAll(".nv-series").size());
```

A d3 selection (the result of `d3.selectAll`) is an array of arrays. As it happens (in your case), the length 3 that you expect could be gotten with `d3.selectAll(".nv-series")[0].length`. But avoid doing that. The reasons for this representation are beyond the scope of this discussion. But the thing to take away is that, perhaps unlike in jQuery, the array representation of a d3 selection is considered internal, so avoid doing any array operations (such as checking `.length`) on it. Instead, use the api methods, like `.size()`, `.node()`, `.empty()` etc.